# how to set a top-down position in a graph networkx

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, directed-graph, digraphs

This is my extended work from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62062012/reproduce-same-graph-in-networkx).
I would like to set the last element `'m'` in the `unique_liss`  appears at the top position of the rest nodes like this[image]. 
However, most of the image generated would be like this:[image]

this is my codes:

```
Unique_liss= ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm']

edgesList= [('a', 'b'), ('b', 'c '), ('c ', 'd'), ('d', 'e'), ('d', 'f'), ('e', 'g'), ('f', 'g'), ('g', 'h'), ('h', 'i '), ('i ', 'j'), ('j', 'k'), ('j', 'l'), ('k', 'm'), ('l', 'm')]

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.DiGraph()
for node in edgesList:
    print('node-', node)
    G.add_edge(*node,sep=',')

A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G).A
import numpy as np
seed = 31
pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_size = 1500,
        seed=seed, node_color = 'skyblue')
```

Although i change the for ..loop into a reversed loop as below:

```
for node in reversed(edgesList):
    print('node-', node)
    G.add_edge(*node,sep=',')
```

it's doesn't guarantees that the last element of the node `'m'` to be appread on the top position of the rest.
Appreciate if anyone can help on how to set the last node to be permanently appear at the top position ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea that updates the positions in the layout based on the relative position of a node of interest to the center of the graph:

```
def get_graph_centroid(pos):
    return np.mean(np.array([a for a in pos.values()]), axis=0)

def find_flip(node_of_interest, pos):

    node_x, node_y = pos[node_of_interest]
    cx, cy = get_graph_centroid(pos)

    flip = [1,1]

    if node_x < cx:
        flip[0] = -1
    if node_y < cy:
        flip[1] = -1

    return flip

def make_flip(pos, flip):

    x,y = flip
    pos = {key: (x*a,y*b) for key, (a,b) in pos.items()}

    return pos



pos = nx.spring_layout(G)
plt.subplot(121)
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_size = 500,
        seed=seed, node_color = 'skyblue')
plt.title('normal layout')

plt.subplot(122)
flip = find_flip('m', pos)
pos = make_flip(pos, flip)
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_size = 500,
        seed=seed, node_color = 'skyblue')
plt.title('flipped layout')
```

[image]

Note that this code only ensures that the node is top right wrt the center, not that is the closest node to the top right corner